# AccountLockException: Error occurred while retrieving http://wso2.org/claims/identity/unlockTime

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I tried to enable account lock in wso2 api manager 3.2.0 and after that I could't able to login in /carbon and after restart server thr exception is as following :

```
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.identity.handler.event.account.lock.exception.AccountLockException: Error occurred while retrieving http://wso2.org/claims/identity/unlockTime , http://wso2.org/claims/identity/failedLoginAttempts and http://wso2.org/claims/identity/failedLoginLockoutCount


Mapped attribute cannot be found for claim : http://wso2.org/claims/identity/failedLoginAttempts in user store : PRIMARY

Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException
```

Comment: Have you configured any secondary user-store in your environment? And have you enabled the mentioned claims in your environment?

Comment: I am not only one that works on APIM, so how can I check that what is wrong, I do not enabled claims or user-store.

Comment: Is this "failedLoginAttempts" claim has mapped to the User Store Domain Name: PRIMARY? Seems like it has been missed.